# How to access the current logged in user's profile page in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access the profile of the user using its id as the url. My problem is that it returns that the id does not exist. Here are some codes that is related to the problem.

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def profile_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
context = {}
user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")

try:
    profile = UserAccount.objects.get(pk=user_id)
except UserAccount.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse("User is not yet registered.")

if profile:
    context['id'] = profile.id
    context['username'] = profile.username
    context['profile_image'] = profile.profile_image
    context['date_joined'] = profile.date_joined

    

    return render(request, 'chat/profile.html', context)
#--------------------
def register(request):
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('home')

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Registered!")
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
return render(request, 'chat/register.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

urls.py:

```
    path('account/<user_id>/', views.profile_view, name='profile_view'),
```

base.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <a class="nav-item" role="presentation" href="{% url 'profile_view' user_id=request.user.id %}">Profile</a>

       <span class="navbar-text actions"><a class="btn btn-light action-button" role="submit" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></span>
{% else %}
       <a class="btn btn-light action-button" role="button" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></span>
{% endif %}
```

Sample run CORRECT:

- Login (as the first created user)
- Clicked profile
- redirects to the `localhost:8000/account/1/`

Sample run Error:

- Login (as the 5th created user)
- Clicked profile
- redirects to `localhost:8000/account/5/` --> gives HttpResponse() under the views.py
- changing the value to 1 `localhost:8000/account/1/` --> gives correct information about the profile as the 5th user

How to fix this kind of error?

Comment: Can you 1. Show your 'register' views.py.  2. Go to Django admin, check the list of users that has been registered i.e. if you have created 5th user, you should have exactly five user objects at django admin. Since HttpResponse("User is not yet registered.") was triggered it would mean that there is no primary key associated with that particular id. So I'd suggest to look at how you are handling their 'registration'. If that doesnt reveal the cause then we continue digging.

Comment: I updated the views.py. Yes, upon checking the admin panel, the 5th user is registered.

Comment: Only the 5th user registered or there are 5-users in total ? This really may well be a user registration handling issue where you do not create new users but simply replace the first user over and over.

Comment: there are 5 users in total. I deleted the 3rd and 4th user. So, there are only 3 users active (1st 2nd and 5th). Under the django-admin, I clicked the 5th and the 3rd user and the url showed what id the user has which is their corresponding id (5 and 3).

Comment: Try as per my answer below; do let me know how it goes.All being said above, I think your models.py is not shown here in full completeness since there are missing fields like profile_image and if you included any customized id field i.e. setting it to be primary key by primary_key=True

Comment: Did my answer below solve your question ?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not working. I have tried check if the id was set to pk=True, it returns true but when I access the url via that pk, it returns nothing.